# Use preg_match for multiple stars (*)

Tags: php

when i try

```
<?php

if(!preg_match('/(******)/',$x)){
echo "bad $x";
}else{
echo "ok $x";

?>
```

i get the following error:  preg_match(): Compilation failed: nothing to repeat

I have also tried

```
<?php

$a = "******";

if(!preg_match('/($a)/',$x)){
echo "bad $x";
}else{
echo "ok $x";

?>
```

but this is not working

Comment: Why `preg_match`? Use `strpos`. If you want to target `*` in regex, you need to escape it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two quotes aren't quite correct

> * is a special character so you need to escape it: \*

> If you want to target * in regex, you need to escape it.

The `*` is a quantifier in regex meaning `0 or more`. Which means that you need to escape it **if** you use it in the normal flow of an expression. However, you don't always need to escape it; if, for example, you use it inside of a character class `[...]` then you have no need to escape it.

Additionally you can use quantifiers to stop yourself having to type out `********************`. If the number doesn't matter you just want to match *at least one* asterisk then you can...

```
\*+
```

...If you want between 1 and 30 then...

```
\*{1,30}
```

...if you want 5 or more...

```
\*{5,}
```

For example:

```
$string = "A string with some ******* in the middle";
 var_dump(
    preg_match('/\*/', $string),        // Matches a single *; esacped *
    preg_match('/[*]/', $string),       // Mathces a single *; character class with *
    preg_match('/\*+/', $string),       // Matches one or more *
    preg_match('/\*{5}/', $string),     // Matches 5 * in a row
    preg_match('/\*{5,}/', $string),    // Matches 5 or more * in a row
    preg_match('/\*{5,10}/', $string),  // Matches between 5 and 10 * in a row
);
```